# Sorting acts-as-taggable on multiple find_related queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a Kid model which includes the following:

```
acts_as_taggable
acts_as_taggable_on :interests, :traits
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :age, :interest_list, :trait_list
```

Where interests can = ["skateboarding","snowboarding","rollerblading"] etc.

and traits can = ["shy","loud","short","tall"] etc.

I am trying to implement a method:

```
def similar_kids
end
```

That returns kids with similar interests, similar traits,  and are close in age. I would also like similar_kids to be sorted by (in this order):

- # of interests + traits in common (DESC)
- age difference (ASC)

IE given.

- Kid A age = 16
- Kid B has 3 interests and 1 trait in common with Kid A, and is 20 years old
- Kid C has 2 interests and 2 traits in common with Kid A, and is 16 years old

The order of similar_kids will be:

- Kid C
- Kid B

Is there a way I can do this efficiently with the gem? It's looking more and more like I'll need to do something custom, but I really like the way things are set up with acts-as-taggable.

Thanks!